# Eigenfunctions of Schrödinger equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, terminology, eigenvalue

Why are solutions of the Schrödinger equation called [eigenfunctions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenfunction)? For an electron moving in one dimensional lattice the eigenfunctions are given by$$\psi(x)=u_k(x)e^{ikx}.$

Comment: Is this a terminology question?

Comment: Don't know what does terminology question means.

Comment: If you want to know more deep why it happens like that you can learn about spectral theory in functional analysis.

Comment: Is it also because of the fact that they are the solutions of the eigen value equation $$H\psi=E\psi$$

Comment: 'Terminology' usually refers to a name - in this case, the name of the quantities we call 'eigenfunctions'. I interpreted it as you wanting to know why eigenfunctions are called 'eigenfunctions'.

Comment: The Schrödinger equation is not just the eigenvalue problem; it is a dynamical equation on the Hilbert space: $i\partial_t\psi(t,x)=H\psi(t,x)$. The solutions of this equation ***are not all eigenfunctions*** of $H$. However, given an eigenfunction (if it exists in the Hilbert space) $\psi_E(x)$ such that $H\psi_E(x)=E\psi_E(x)$ ($E\in\mathbb{R}$), then the associated solution $\psi_E(t,x)$ of the Schrödinger equation with $\psi_E(0,x)=\psi_E(x)$ (initial condition) is quite simple: $\psi_E(t,x)=e^{-itE}\psi_E(x)$. Additionally, $\psi_E(t,x)$ is an eigenfunction for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [eigenvalue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) is something physicists should be familiar with. For some matrix, $A$, multiplied by some vector $\mathbf x$, we get
$$
A\mathbf x=\lambda\mathbf x \tag{1}
$$
where $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue, a characteristic of $A$ on $\mathbf x$.

An [eigenfunction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenfunction) is related to Equation (1). Given an [*operator*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map) (a differential operator in the case of quantum mechanics), $\mathcal{A}$, acting on a [*function*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)), $f(x)$, we have the relation,
$$
\mathcal{A}f=\lambda f\tag{2}
$$
where $\lambda$ is still called the eigenvalue. A function that satisfies this relationship is called the **eigenfunction**.

Note that not every function satisfies this relationship. For instance, given $\mathcal{A}=\frac{d}{dx}$ (first-order differential operator) and $f(x)=x^2$, the resulting operation is
$$
\mathcal{A}f=\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^2\right)=2x\neq\lambda f(x)
$$
so this does not satisfy (2). However, if $f(x)=e^{kx}$, then
$$
\mathcal{A}f=\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{kx}\right)=ke^{kx}=kf(x)
$$
which does satisfy (2) with eigenvalue $\lambda=k$.